# In Solr (Sunspot) is there an equivalent to ThinkingSphinx's "excerpts" functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, thinking-sphinx, sunspot

I had found excerpts to be very useful in ThinkingSphinx (http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/excerpts.html). Is there an equivalent of this in Sunspot for Rails?

Answer (score 1):

```
search = Model.search do
  fulltext "words" do
    highlight :some_field
  end
end
```

More at [Sunspot solr page](http://sunspot.github.com/sunspot/docs/#Highlighting)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm now running into the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161499/how-highlight-found-word-with-sunspot. Also, I'm using the :fragment_size option, but it still returns the entire body of text. Any ideas?